# Issues with animation - translation, projection OpenGL/C++

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, opengl-compat

Recently I had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61796907/why-does-my-wired-sphere-turn-into-ellipsoid-when-translating-and-changing-camer/61799465?noredirect=1#comment109316474_61799465) issue. Now that I've fixed that with given solution, I ran into some other issues. [Here is a gif](https://postimg.cc/nCW5XTqM) of the animation I have to achieve.

Issues I have now are: the ball in my animation doesn't look like it's moving forwards and backwards like it is at the beginning of the .gif. I do believe this has something to do with Ortho but I don't know how to fix this.

Also, at some point, when it's moving completely to the right, the moving ball and torus just get "swallowed", it's visible only at the starting point and slowly disappears when translating along z-axis. Here is the code I have.

```
void display(void) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(0.26f, 0.74f, 0.73f);
    glutWireTorus(0.2, 0.85, 17, 30);

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, tra);
    glColor3f(0.9f, 0.5f, 0.3f);
    glutWireSphere(0.5, 17, 15);

    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(ex+0.0, ey+0.0, ez+10.0, cx, cy, cz, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glFlush();
    }

void reshape(int w, int h) {
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    float sx = w / 70.0f;
    float sy = h / 70.0f;
    glOrtho(-sx/2.0f, sx/2.0f, -sy/2.0f, sy/2.0f, 1.0f, 600.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

I believe there are some mistakes inside this part.

Comment: *"he ball in my animation doesn't look like it's moving forwards and backwards like it is at the beginning of the .gif."*. Do switch from perspective projection to orthographic projection? If you want that the size of the object decrease by the distance to the camera, then you have to use perspective projection, but that will cause a perspective distortion.

Comment: @Rabbid76 that does fix it but then when I resize the window everything changes its shape. Maybe it's the aspect ratio, I really don't know.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I just have to achieve exactly the same animation as given above, with the condition that changing the window size doesn't change object shape. That is my homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a perspective projection, where the size of the objects is relative to screen resolution and independent on the the size of the window, then you have to compute the filed of view angle in relation to the height of the window:

```cpp
void reshape(int w, int h) {
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    float angle_rad = atan((float)h / 600.0f) * 2.0f;
    float angle_deg = angle_rad * 180.0f / M_PI;
    gluPerspective(angle_deg, (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h, 1.0, 80.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

The relation between the field of view angle and the size of an object is `tan(fov / 2) * 2.`, thus the `fov = atan(size) * 2`, where `size` depends on the size of the window (`(float)h / 600.0f`).
You have to adjust the divider (`600.0f`) for your needs.

Comment: I think this worked. I now have to play with gluLookAt to get the effect I want. I hope that doesn't bring me any new issues. Thank you so much for your help once again.

Comment: @me995 Thank you. I am glad to help.